# What happens when an iOS device cannot allocate memory? (eg. when it has run out of memory)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, ios4

If an iOS device cannot successfully [NSObject alloc] (because it is out of memory), will it return nil, throw an exception, or will the OS terminate the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are stages. You will receive memory warnings when the device is running low on memory. You see these in template classes as `-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods. This is the place where you release anything you don't need, and it's also where the OS starts unloading objects.

The second stage is that your application is terminated.

Comment: Hi . I'm facing this problem when continuously swapping between two items at MasterViewController (Using SplitviewController). Using ARC .May I know How to overcome from this crash issue. Thanking You

Comment: @KumarKl: you need to ask a new question or look around to see if someone has asked something similar, and include (relevant) code so we can see where things are going wrong. :)